# add and remove class javascript(no jquery)

Tags: javascript, classname

could anyone please help to remove the class when the next element is clicked.

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
  var divContainer = document.getElementById(i.toString());
  divContainer.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    const audio = document.getElementById('audio_' + event.target.id);
    audio.play();
    const picActive = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
    picActive.className += " active";
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="keys">
  <div id="1" class="key">
    <img id="1" src="images/cow.png" alt="Cow" height="180" width="180">
    <span class="sound">Cow</span>
    <audio id="audio_1" src="sounds/moo.mp3"></audio>
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="key">
    <img id="2" src="images/sheep.png" alt="Sheep" height="180" width="180">
    <span class="sound">Sheep</span>
    <audio id="audio_2" src="sounds/baa.mp3"></audio>
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="key">
    <img id="3" src="images/pig.png" alt="Pig" height="180" width="180">
    <span class="sound">Pig</span>
    <audio id="audio_3" src="sounds/grunt.mp3" />
  </div>
</div>
```

How should I remove the "active" class from one clicked element and add it to the next which is clicked? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use classList property of that element which is an array so you can call add and remove on it `.classList.add('class name')` `.classList.remove('class name')`

Comment: Thank you very much! That perfectly works! Yay!

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
     var divContainer = document.getElementById(i.toString());
     divContainer.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
         const audio = document.getElementById('audio_' + event.target.id);
         audio.play();
         for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
             document.getElementById(j.toString()).classList.remove("active");
         };
         const picActive = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
         picActive.className += " active";
     });
 };
```

Comment: If you're using `classList` already to remove a class, you should also use it to add it.